# Elastic Search filtered aliases with unmapped fields

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-mapping

I recently started playing around with `filtered aliases` in Elastic Search [(documentation here)](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html) but there is use case which I am not sure how to approach.

**Use Case**

Each document that I index in ElasticSearch for a fact is going to have a field called "tenantId" (and also some other fields such as "type", "id" etc). Now all the documents reside in the same index, so per Tenant I want to make sure I create a filtered alias. Now I want to create the filtered alias as soon as I have created the tenant itself and have the "tenantId" handy.

**Problem**

When I tried to create the alias programmatically using their java client, I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryParsingException: 
     [mdm-master] Strict field resolution and no field mapping 
     can be found for the field with name [tenantId]
```

Researching more, I found out that I can probably use dynamic templates in order to achieve this. So I created a template, saved it under `config/templates`, recreated my index and tried the same thing again. Got the same exception again. On reading the documentation more [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-dynamic-mapping.html) (bottom 3 lines on the page), I found out that even if I would try to change the following property `index.query.parse.allow_unmapped_fields` to true (which I didn't try yet), for filtered aliases, it will force it to false.

Now the question is, how do I approach my usecase? I do not know the mappings of the corresponding types but what I do know for a fact is each document that I index, regardless of the type, will ALWAYS have a field called `tenantId` and that's what I want to create my filtered alias on.

**EDIT**

Couple of helpful links that I found. Not sure which version is this fixed on.
 [filtered aliases in templates do not inherit mappings from aliased index #8473](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/8473) 
 [index.query.parse.allow_unmapped_fields setting does not seem to allow unmapped fields in alias filters #8431](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/8431)

**SECOND EDIT**

Found an open bug for ElasticSearch with the exact same problem. Waiting on ES developers for a response.  [Failure to create Filtered Alias on empty index with template mappings #10038](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/10038)

All help is extremely appreciated ! I have been trying to figure this out from couple of days now with no luck :(.

Following is the code I used to add the filtered alias, and the default mapping json template

**Template**

```
{
  "template-1": {
    "template": "*",
    "mappings": {
      "_default_": {
        "properties": {
          "type": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          },
          "id": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          },
          "tenantId": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**JAVA CLIENT**

(You can ignore the "Observable" related stuff for now)

```
public Observable<Boolean> createAlias(String tenantId) {

        FilterBuilder filter = FilterBuilders.termFilter("tenantId", tenantId);
        ListenableActionFuture<IndicesAliasesResponse> response = client.admin().indices().prepareAliases().addAlias("mdm-master", tenantId, filter).execute();
        return Observable.from(response)
                .map((IndicesAliasesResponse apiResponse) -> {
                    return apiResponse.isAcknowledged();
                });
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm the guy who posted that latest issue on ES Github [Failure to create Filtered Alias on empty index with template mappings #10038](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/10038). The quickest workaround I've found for now (except downgrading to 1.3, where this issue does not exist), is to index a document with the field before creating the alias.

If you have one index with many tenants, you should only need to index a document with the required field once when you create the index, and then you should be able to create the alias.

If you try the reproduction case I posted in the GitHub issue, but before creating the alias, run the following:

```
curl -XPOST  'http://localhost:9200/repro/dummytype/1' -d '{
   "testfield": "dummyvalue"
}'
```

Then you should be able to add a filtered alias on the field `testfield`.

**Edit - Answer to first comment:**
I think that it's an oversight when you use mapping in templates. A template is applied to matching index when the index is created. I think the issue here is that the generic mapping part of the template isn't *actually* applied until it gets a document indexed.
This behaviour can be observed if you change my template in the issue to the following:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/_template/repro' -d '{
  "template": "repro",
  "settings": {
    "index.number_of_shards": 1,
    "index.number_of_replicas": 0
  },
  "mappings": {
    "dummytype": {
      "properties": {
        "testfield": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Then you're able to create the index and add the filtered alias without indexing any documents.

As I said, I think this is a bug in the template application in ES.

Comment: Yes. I actually tried that and it worked for me, although I still don't understand why I have to provide a mapping with a specific type. From a design perspective, a filtered alias shouldn't have to do anything with "type" per se, but only with mapping of a specific field and it should be client's responsibility to make sure that field is present in all the indexed documents (if at all that's their usecase). ES shouldn't make that decision for the clients though but something more configurable.